# Can I create One Box Job inside another box job in Autosys by JIL

Tags: automation, autosys

I want to write a JIL file in which I want One major box then inside this box job another box job and then I want to write a command Job.

I haven't been able to find the syntax and also Is it possible to write one box job inside another box job or not.

Comment: It's possible ... For the sub box job ... Add the child box in the box attribute

Comment: @Piyush, Can you give me a sample script or command to add the sub box job in the JIL file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following names:

Major_Box - the parent box
Child_Box - the child box
Job_A - CMD job under the child box

Sample JIL:

```
insert_job: Major_Box
job_type: BOX
owner: xyz
date_conditions: 1
days_of_week: all
start_times: "06:00"
timezone: IST

insert_job: Child_Box
job_type: BOX
box_name: Major_Box
owner: xyz
date_conditions: 1
days_of_week: all
start_times: "06:15"
timezone: IST

insert_job: Job_A
job_type: CMD
box_name: Child_Box
command: bash /absolute_path/script_name.sh
owner: xyz
machine: hostname
date_conditions: 1
days_of_week: all
start_times: "06:30"
timezone: IST
```

Here,

Major_Box would be triggered at 6:00, it would activate the Child_box but not trigger it.

At 6:15 the Activated Child_Box would be triggered as the time condition is true, thus activating the Job_A.

At 6:30 the activated Job_A would trigger running the commands as mentioned.

Also, you are include condition of preceding job/box

```
condition: Success(Another_Job)
```

Hope this helps. Let me know if you need more.
Good Luck